# Peewee каскадное удаление

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, peewee

Есть такая модель:

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase('storage.db')

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class Holders(BaseModel):
    user_id = IntegerField()

class Chats(BaseModel):
    username = TextField()
    chat_id = IntegerField()
    holder = ForeignKeyField(Holders, backref='chats')
    delete_files = BooleanField(default=True)

class Members(BaseModel):
    user_id = IntegerField()
    reputation = IntegerField(default=0)
    chat = ForeignKeyField(Chats, backref='chats', on_delete='cascade')
    join_date = DateTimeField()
    level = IntegerField(default=0)

class BlockedChannels(BaseModel):
    username = TextField()
    chat = ForeignKeyField(Chats, backref='channels', on_delete='cascade')

class BlockedDomains(BaseModel):
    domain = TextField()
    chat = ForeignKeyField(Chats, backref='domains', on_delete='cascade')
```

В моём понимании при удалении объекта `Chat` все те, кто на него ссылался должны быть удалены, но этого не происходит:

```
holder = Holders.create(user_id=1337)
chat = Chats.create(username='@test', chat_id='1488', holder=holder)
BlockedDomains.create(domain='text', chat=chat)
user = Members.create(user_id=123, join_date=str(datetime.now()), chat=chat)
chat.delete_instance()  # удаляем
```

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Причина в использовании sqlite. В [документации](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/relationships.html#creating-test-data) pewee рекомендуют сделать следующее `db = SqliteDatabase('storage.db', pragmas={'foreign_keys': 1})`.

Comment: @godva спасибо, не могли бы вы оформить это в ответ чтобы я отметил его как верный?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Причина кроется в настройках sqlite, а именно в значении прагмы [foreign_keys](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys), которая начиная с версии SQLite 3.6.19 имеет значение OFF. В [документации](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/relationships.html#creating-test-data) pewee для работы foreign_key предлагают включить прагму `foreign_keys` следующими образом:

```
db = SqliteDatabase('storage.db', pragmas={'foreign_keys': 1})
```